# Заполнение одного чекбокса по клику на ссылку

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Я сделал спойлеры, преобразовав чекбоксы с помощью CSS.

```
CSS
.del {display: none;}
.del:not(:checked) + label + * {display: none;}

.del:not(:checked) + label, .del:checked + label {display: inline-block; color: #3778CD; border-bottom: 1px dashed; cursor: pointer;}
.del:checked + label {color: #3778CD;border-bottom: 1px dashed;font-weight: bold;}

HTML
<input class="del" id="name1" type="checkbox" />
<label class="del" for="name1">NAME</label>
<div>       
SPOILER
</div>
```

При клике по NAME спойлер раскрывается. Все работает.

Теперь нужно, чтобы **по клику на определенную ссылку** (например, ссылку с якорем) на странице со спойлером этот спойлер раскрывался = **чекбокс заполнился**. Я так понимаю, это можно сделать через JS. Как это сделать максимально просто? Например, вставить onClick в ссылку.

Update: спойлеров на странице много, ссылок с якорями тоже; id для якоря и спойлера нужно делать разными, чтобы всё работало корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/zyumr4hw

**HTML**

```
<input class="del" id="name1" type="checkbox" />
<label class="del" for="name1">NAME</label>
<div id="spoiler">       
SPOILER
</div>
<a href="#" id="link">Link</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.del {display: none;}
.del:not(:checked) + label + * {display: none;}

.del:not(:checked) + label, .del:checked + label {display: inline-block; color: #3778CD; border-bottom: 1px dashed; cursor: pointer;}
.del:checked + label {color: #3778CD;border-bottom: 1px dashed;font-weight: bold;}

.spoiler {display:none}
```

**JS**

```
var showSpoiler = function() {
    document.getElementById("name1").setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    document.getElementById("spoiler").style.display="block";
};

document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", showSpoiler, false);
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как быть, если спойлеров на странице очень много (name1, name2 ...) и на каждый будет своя ссылка? Можно в JS-коде указать не "name1", а какое-нибудь универсальное значение?

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать ссылки с якорем, ссылающиеся на чекбоксы с соответствующим id, то можно воспользоваться следующим: при клике на ссылку с якорем (слушаем событие [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)) или при переходе по URL с уже имеющимся якорем (загрузка страницы), в `window.location.hash` будет собственно лежать сам якорь (id). Зная это, по id можно найти чекбокс и активировать его:

HTML:

```
<div class="anchor" id="name1anch"></div>
<input class="del" id="name1" type="checkbox" />
<label class="del" for="name1">NAME</label>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div>

<div class="anchor" id="name2anch"></div>
<input class="del" id="name2" type="checkbox" />
<label class="del" for="name2">NAME</label>
<div>
    Quis possimus obcaecati iste amet omnis placeat
</div>

<!-- ... -->

<a href="#name1anch">Name 1</a>
<a href="#name2anch">Name 2</a>
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', showSpoiler);
showSpoiler();

function showSpoiler() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if (!hash) { return; } // пустой хеш

  // хеш в начале строки имеет символ '#', и так получилось, что
  // для поиска по id тоже нужен символ '#'
  var id = hash;

  // ищем якорь по id
  var anchor = document.querySelector(id);
  if (!anchor) { return; } // якоря не существует
  // следующий за якорем элемент - чекбокс
  var cb = anchor.nextElementSibling;

  // либо если чекбокс находится в другом месте
  // но id чекбокса и якоря зависимы, то можно
  // искать чекбокс по id, нужно откомментировать
  // var cbId = id.replace('anch', '');
  // var cb = document.querySelector(cbId);

  if (cb && cb.type.toLowerCase() === 'checkbox') {
    cb.checked = true;
  }
}
```

Правка: Обновил код в соответствии с комментариями, добавил ссылку на пример.

Рабочий вариант [здесь](http://jsbin.com/goqupifosu/edit?html,css,js,output).

Comment: Спасибо! У чекбокса и якоря разные id. Например: <div class="anchor" id="name1anch"></div>    <input class="del" id="name1" type="checkbox" />. Если id одинаковые, спойлер не раскрывается. В результате клик по ссылке <a href="#name1">Name 1</a> приводит к раскрытию спойлера без перехода к нему, а клик по ссылке <a href="#name1anch">Name ЯКОРЬ</a> к переходу без раскрытия спойлера.

Comment: Естественно, если меняются требования, то и код чаще всего нужно модифицировать. Я привел решение к проблеме и коду, которые вы описали в вопросе. Если все-таки нужны дополнительные правки, обновите, пожалуйста, код в вопросе, и я постараюсь подстроить свой ответ под него + другие пользователи смогут ориентироваться на актуальную версию вопроса.

Comment: Подправил свой вариант + добавил ссылку на пример. Надеюсь, что правильно вас понял и представил HTML код в нужной структуре.

Comment: Работает! Михаил, огромное спасибо!